# Docker - cached mounted volume syncing delay

Tags: php, symfony, docker, docker-compose, containers

I'm building a local development environment using docker compose on macOS. We have multiple applications that are written in php and run with Symfony. The code is attached to the containers via a volume. I encountered a very poor performance compared to linux hosts.

It turned out that the problem is caused by mounted volume that is based on osxfs, a shared file system solution, exclusive to Docker for Mac.

The issue is nicely explained here: https://blog.docker.com/2017/05/user-guided-caching-in-docker-for-mac/

The performance has improved greatly after introducing cached mode of the mounted volumes. However, it allows some delays before updates on the host appear in the container. The documentation is not specific about this delay. Do you know how fast is the syncing between the code on the host and inside the container?

```
volumes:
  - ./php_code:/var/www:cached
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **NFS** *(doesn't work with High Sierra - [more details here](https://github.com/adlogix/docker-machine-nfs/issues/79))*

> docker-machine-nfs ${DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME}
>   --mount-opts="noacl,async,nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1"

2. Keep your **PHP cache inside the container** - for example in `/tmp/app_cache/*` - alternatively in Memory `/dev/shm/app_cache/*` (not recomended)

To keep cache inside the container change in your `AppKernel.php` (for Symfony 4.0 `Kernel.php`)

```
...    
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if ($this->environment === 'env') {
        // Store in RAM.
        // return '/dev/shm/symfony_docker_test/cache/'.$this->environment;

        // Store in docker container (not docker-machine unless docker-compose volume is mounted).
        return '/tmp/symfony_cache/cache/' . $this->environment;
    }

    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}
...
```

Results with solutions mentioned **and** `:cached`

```
Time taken for tests:   20.396 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      82700 bytes
HTML transferred:       31900 bytes
Requests per second:    4.90 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       203.963 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       203.963 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3.96 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Results with solutions mentioned **without** `:cached`

```
Time taken for tests:   18.911 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      82700 bytes
HTML transferred:       31900 bytes
Requests per second:    5.29 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       189.111 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       189.111 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          4.27 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Comment: Option 2 is preferable. The whole point about Docker is to have everything that makes up your application in versioned images.

Comment: Thanks for this, The results are very interesting. Do you think that it was measured with a warm :cached?  I'll check if we can move the cache folder into the container. Also NFS may be helpful. Another option is docker-sync http://docker-sync.io/ However, the question is: what is the delay before updates on the host appear in the container when using cached mode for volume mounting.

Comment: @Ludek Keep playing with other solutions. Although I know any that increases speed significantly without drawbacks. `:chached` as you’ve noticed causes sync delays. I would stick to these above because they don’t cause any major issues. The speed increase is significant and sufficient to develop env. Cheers.

Comment: How can I recognise that my volumes are cached after using that option ? I use docker-compose.override.yml ?

Comment: @Artur79 If you define them to be ‘:chached’ they are cached. If you want to see volumes use ‘docker volumes [cmd]’